# How do you stop your friends from being notified of what you post on others' walls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, privacy, facebook-privacy, facebook-notifications

With Facebook, if you go to for example a company's page and post something on their wall, or even another friend's page, how do you stop it from *notifying* all your friends of what you posted?

I don't care if they visit the actual company's/other friend's page and see it, but I don't want all my friends being *notified* of what I posted.

Is there a way to do this? I can't see anything in Facebook's privacy settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are frequent poster (means if you keep updating status, sharing etc), they will not get any notification but if you are posting something after a long time (3 weeks or more), they will get notifcation. There is no control.

If you are writting something on your friend's wall, only they can control who can see that. You can't do anything in that, it will be visible to all your friends.

If you are writting something on any Page, it will be public.

There is no privacy setting to control this.

Comment: Yes I know that, as I said I don't care if they visit the page and see it - and yes I know only the persons page that is on can only be controlled by them; but what I'm asking is how to stop it from notifying my friends that I posted it; they don't need to know about everything I post and where.

Comment: If you are frequent poster (means if you keep updating status, sharing etc), they will not get any notification but if you are posting something after a long time (3 weeks or more), they will get notifcation. There is no control.

Comment: @pnuts: OP can try that, but I think that will not help.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I should add the comment into answer.

Comment: Well I'm not too frequent no....... but anyway, that's pretty stupid there is nothing to control that. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to stop this unfortunately. One solution I thought of would be to create an separate Facebook account for doing things which you don't want the friends of your original account to know about.